# Как глобально изменить сообщения об ошибках в YII2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Здравствуйте.

У моделей в Yii2 есть поле для кастомного сообщения, для Javascript валидации на стороне клиента:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['url', 'shop_id', 'group_id', 'group_name'], 
           'required', 'message'=>'Введите значение {attribute}.'],
```

Но это приходиться писать в каждой модели.
А вот как глобально сменить сообщения валидации JS, чтобы не писать в каждой модели одно и тоже?  [image: Сообщения об ошибках валидации]
http://joxi.ru/vAWR7KpfkypM92
Сайт на русском языке, так что было бы очень удобно централизованно редактировать системные сообщения.

Comment: Наверное надо задать в конфиге язык приложения русский....потому что при соответствующей настройке сообщения будут браться из папки `vendor\yiisoft\yii2\messages\ru` где прописан шаблон `'{attribute} cannot be blank.' => 'Необходимо заполнить «{attribute}».',` к примеру...... так что скорее всего всё упирается в настройку языка и локали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо. Вы направили меня в правильном направлении. С вашей помошью задал правильный вопрос гуглу. Вот ссылка ответ  http://pro-cod.ru/yii2-ustanovit-russkij-yazyk.html